# Why can't I work with files in ".." from within a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have the following directory structure:

```
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp$ ls -l
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 misha lmd 21 Feb 18 21:00 hello.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 misha lmd 20 Feb 18 21:01 symlink -> /home/misha/nobackup/
```

Next, I try the following:

```
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp$ cd symlink
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp/symlink$ cat ../hello.py 
cat: ../hello.py: No such file or directory
```

Why doesn't this work?

If I do this instead:

```
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp/symlink$ cd ..
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp$ cat hello.py
print "Hello World!"
```

Then all is well.  cd handles .. properly, but cat doesn't.  What is this sorcery, and how do I make things work the way I want them to?

**EDIT**

OK, thanks to some of the answers here, I've found out a bit more about what's going on.  First, `cd` is not actually an executable, it is a built-in command of the shell (in this case, bash):

```
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

If you `man bash`, you can find all about the environment variables that bash uses for its housekeeping, including moving around directories.  There are other built-ins, like `pwd`, that have counterparts that are actually executables:

```
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp/symlink$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp/symlink$ /bin/pwd
/home/misha/nobackup
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp/symlink$ /bin/pwd -L
/home/misha/tmp/symlink
```

The `/bin/pwd` executable prints the physical path by default, but can also print the logical path given the `-L' switch.  Similarly, when I try to do:

```
misha@misha-lmd:~/tmp/symlink$ cat ../hello.py 
cat: ../hello.py: No such file or directory
```

things are failing because `..` is being interpreted as the *physical* parent directory, not the *logical one*.  This allows me to **refine my question** as:

When I specify a command-line argument to an executable, how can I get `..` to mean the logical parent, not the physical one?

Comment: What is `/home/misha/nobackup/`? Is it an existing directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the directory `..` in your symlinked directory is your home directory.

`../something` means "go to the `..` directory", not "strip the last path component".

You can try `pwd -P` to see where you are, after you change into symlink.

Comment: If, from within the symlinked directory, .. is ~, why does "cd .." take me back to ~/tmp instead of the ~?  Is cd doing something clever that cat doesn't do?

Comment: Yes, bash does "something clever". Just try `man bash` and look for `cd` (`/^ +cd` should get you there).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because there's no `/home/misha/hello.py`. A symbolic link does not create a new directory, but points to the one linked. So when you cd to a symbolic link, you actually cd to that directory,

Did you expect the shell will remember from where you came from a symbolic link? Well, doesn't work like that :)

Comment: Umm... Well, the shell actually does remember, as you cas easily see in prompt ;-)

Comment: The question was caused by `cd` command actually *working like that* (unless it's `cd -P`), as opposed to `..` pathname interpretation in system calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cat $(cd ..; pwd)/hello.pycat
```

Don't know if it helps you.

**EDIT:**
If you **really** need it, here is a way to do it (but it's kind of ugly):

```
$ lcat ( ) ( cd "${1%/*}"; cat "${1##*/}"; )
# use it like 'cat'
$ lcat ../hello.py
```

Using `( ... )` instead of `{ ... }` for the function body makes it do the `cd` in a sub shell instead of the current shell.
When I try it it works also with "file name completion".
But this is only solving `cat`, it can be more complex to use for other commands as well I think.

```
$ lcmd ( ) ( local cmd="$1"; shift; cd "${1%/*}"; $cmd "${1##*/}"; )
```

Then do e.g. `lcmd cat ../hello.py`

Comment: Thank you.  While that works, it's really verbose, and it breaks autocompletion.